# Jquery Datatable Pagination: Listbox combined with Full numbers

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to display a listbox along with full numbers pagination. How can I combine both of them?

[image: Attached Image - for pagination]

Comment: It's working for you?? http://jsfiddle.net/urwyrj89/2/

Answer (score 1):

Check http://legacy.datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination
The last example is about `select-list` pagination.

They have examples for the legacy version, but it's applicable to datatables 1.10+

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do with Select list

Example:
Import [select.js](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/pagination/select.js) along with your datatable js files

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
          "sPaginationType": "listbox"
      } );
  } );
```